# What is the use of the Party Points currency?

Tags: super-mario-party

I get 'Party Points' everytime I finish a game, or a challenge in Mario Party.

Is it used for anything? It feels like it's a currency of some sort, but can't figure out where to spend it.

PS: Might not be party points, maybe it's more 'Party Tickets'? Don't have the game right now to confirm.

Comment: -1: I Googled "mario party party points" and found the answer for how you can start using them, and what you can use them for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing some of the games, a Toad in the party plaza will wave. If you talk to him, you can spend the points on advice, stickers, and music tracks. Not all options will be available from the start, more will be unlocked as you play.